How to load obj file with mtl in Mitsuba
In mitsuba documentation 0.5.0, it states that obj files .mtl files can be automatically loaded. I currently have a obj file where some parts of it are red and some parts are blue (all using the simplest diffuse model). I opened the obj file with windows 3d viewer and it looks fine. However, if I simply add the obj in mitsuba as:
<shape type="obj" id="myshape">
    <string name="filename" value="myshape.obj"/>
</shape>

then it renders the whole obj as a grayish diffuse surface.
Did I miss anything here or loading obj with .mtl files are no longer supported in Mitsuba?
